# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orWhere does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I got problem Method `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orWhere` does not exist. I just wanna use orWhere on that case

I tried adding `->get()` in the last query but it still error

```
$category = Auth::user()->division->allCode->where('parent', '0')->where('info_code', 'code_h')
            ->orWhere('info_code','=', 'code_m')->where('parent', '0');
```

I want to use or where in this case and get the result. here the logic I want

```
(parent==0 && info_code == code_h) || (parent==0 && info_code == code_m)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `()` after allCode like: `Auth::user()->division->allCode()->where...`

Comment: I don't get this. can you please teach me?
I have this problem

$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications
    ->where('type', 'App\Notifications\UserUpdate')->orWhere('type', 'App\Notifications\PostUpdate')->take(10);

`"Method Illuminate\\Notifications\\DatabaseNotificationCollection::orWhere does not exist."`

Comment: Calling method will give hasMany class which you can continue modifying your query. If you call the prop with the same name as the relation method; it is like notifications()->get() which will return a model collection and not query builder. Because the model collection also has where method as like as builder, you get the error on orWhere call.